# How to quickly move to a real directory using a soft link directory in linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a dir `/var/real-dir`

I've created a soft link to it like this

```
ln -s /var/realdir /var/virtual-dir
```

Having that my working directory is `/var/virtual-dir`, I'm searching for a way to cd to `real-dir` with as less typing as possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "fast move"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cd -P .`

Note that this only updates the `PWD` and `OLDPWD` environment variables; the kernel-level current directory remains unchanged.

Alternatively, you can use the `-P` option with the initial `cd` like `cd -P /var/virtual-dir`.

Answer (score 2):

You can:

```
cd "$(readlink -f .)"
```

If this is too much typing, you can create a helper function in your `.bashrc`, like this:

```
function cdlink() {
    cd "$(readlink -f .)"
}
```

`source ~/.bashrc` or start a new shell and can simply type:

```
cdlink
```